# Descenders of letters get cropped out when using -webkit-line-clamp with reduced line-height

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to limit the number of lines a title can be using `-webkit-line-clamp`. However, because the title also has a reduced `line-height` letters that have descenders ("g", "j", "p", "q", and "y") get cropped off on the bottom line. How can I fix this so the descenders of these letters do not get cropped out?

```css
p {
    width: 140px;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    word-break: break-word;
    display: -webkit-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 1;
}

p.small {
    width: 100px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

p.large {
    font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<p title='The "g" in this title gets cut off at the bottom'>The "g" in this title gets cut off at the bottom</p>
<p class="large" title='The "g" in this title gets cut off at the bottom'>The "g" in this title gets cut off at the bottom</p>
<p class="small" title='The "g" in this title gets cut off at the bottom'>The "g" in this title gets cut off at the bottom</p>
```

Comment: So why limit the line-height since that is the problem?

Comment: Reducing the line height makes the title take up less space and look better imo. The same reason I'm using line-clamp to limit the number of lines in the first place. https://imgur.com/ijQz4s2

Comment: Well the only way to avoid this issue to to have a line height of  1 or greater. that's the point of `line-height`.

Comment: @Paulie_D Obviously this is not true. I have edited the snippet and with a `line-height` of `1` descenders are still getting cut off. Interestingly this does not happen if the text is small.

Comment: Updated to show the problem happens more aggressively when using bootstrap, including at smaller text sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to deal with such situation before and I used bit of a trick to add padding at the bottom just relative to `font-size` so that it doesn't display next line and keep text still readable.

To fix the issue, add `padding-bottom: 0.14em;` style to `p` element. I have noticed values between 0.12 to 0.15 working best with different font families.

```css
p {
    width: 140px;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    word-break: break-word;
    display: -webkit-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 1;
    padding-bottom: 0.14em;
}

p.small {
    width: 100px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

p.large {
    font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<p title='The "g" in this title gets cut off at the bottom'>The "g" in this title gets cut off at the bottom</p>
<p class="large" title='The "g" in this title gets cut off at the bottom'>The "g" in this title gets cut off at the bottom</p>
<p class="small" title='The "g" in this title gets cut off at the bottom'>The "g" in this title gets cut off at the bottom</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same issue with Tailwind line-clamp plugin (which is effectively identical to the above described attributes using class `line-clamp-2`).

Poppins seems to be a terrible font for this. It clips the bottom of the letter `g` with `padding-bottom: 0.0725em` and it reveals the top of the next line (ie: the top of the hidden clamped area) with `padding-bottom: 0.073em`.

I fixed my issue by instead changing line-height from `1` to `1.3` and no bottom-padding. It increases the padding between each line of text, but could be arguably-negligible.