# The lowest bottom part of fonts is cut off when using -webkit-line-clamp

Tags: css, fonts

When using following css on h3 element, lowest parts of fonts on last line are cut-off.

```
-webkit-line-clamp: 3;
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
overflow: hidden;
```

Font-size is 33px and line-height 1.12

[image: Fonts cut off]

It happens consistently on firefox and chrome.
I found [a fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63977541/descenders-of-letters-get-cropped-out-when-using-webkit-line-clamp-with-reduced), however, I would like to know why it happens, am I missing something or is it a browser-consistent bug?

Comment: I suspect perhaps on calculations for cutting being performed while default font is loaded and shown, and font swapping occurs later.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. Could you put up a working snippet - with the relevant font and anything else of relevance like width and overflow settings?

Comment: I will try to reproduce it. It may also be font dependent. Try with google fonts Open Sans, font-size: 33px; and font-weight: 700;

Comment: I have exactly the same problem! Part of bottom text letters are cut off